# How do you implement a dummy link_to in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing, link-to

OK, so I'm just migrating my first project from Rails 3 to Rails 4, the project is under development and so has certain links that are only there for the sake of content.

In Rails 3 I could do this:

```
link_to "To be added", {:controller => "#", :action => "#"}
```

This would give me a dummy link that I could style etc. This does not work in Rails 4 due to a routing error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"#", :controller=>"#"}
```

It could just be that I'm slightly sleep deprived at the moment but I can't seem to figure out a decent way of solving this and achieving the same functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And why not something like: `link_to "To be added", "#"`?

Answer (score 2):

I just use <%= link_to "To be added" %>

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried it out before answering my own question like a douche, but no good, for some reason no styling was being added (it wasn't applying any ids or classes to be more specific)